# Create hierarchical multidimensional array based on number of consecutive symbols at start of strings

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, hierarchical-data

I'm not sure that the title is correct as it's hard to explain.
I want to convert a 1 dimensional array into a multidimensional array based on each array's hashtag count.

So basically I want this.

```php
[
    0 => "# Grandparent #1"
    1 => "# Grandparent #2"
    2 => "## Parent #2-1"
    3 => "### Child #2-1-1"
    4 => "## Parent #2-2"
    5 => "### Child #2-2-1"
    6 => "### Child #2-2-2"
    7 => "## Parent #2-3"
    8 => "## Parent #2-4"
    9 => "# Grandparent #3"
    10 => "## Parent #3-1"
]
```

To something like this

```php
[
    [
        'name' => 'Grandparent #1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Grandparent #2',
        'children' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Parent #2-1',
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Child #2-1-1',
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Parent #2-2',
                'children' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Child #2-2-1'
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'Child #2-2-2'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Parent #2-3',
            ],
            [ 
                'name' => 'Parent #2-4',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'name' 'Grandparent #3',
        'children' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Parent #3-1'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

My code:
Data set is minimal reproducible example.
There can also be a infinite amount of `#` after the previous.
The 2nd hashtags (#2-1-1) are used to provide clarity, not part of the issue.

```php
$array = [
    "# Grandparent #1",
    "# Grandparent #2",
    "## Parent #2-1",
    "### Child #2-1-1",
    "## Parent #2-2",
    "### Child #2-2-1",
    "### Child #2-2-2",
    "## Parent #2-3",
    "## Parent #2-4",
    "# Grandparent #3",
    "## Parent #3-1",
];
function structure($lines, $target = 1) {
    $data = [];
    $parent = 0;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $current = strlen(preg_split('/\s+/', $line)[0]);
        if ($current == $target) {
            $parent = $i;
            $data[$parent]['name'] = $line;
        }
        if ($current != $target) {
            $data[$parent]['children'][] = $line;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    // I tried placing structure function here again but it gives me errors
    // structure($data[$parent]['children'], $target + 1);
    return $data;
}

$data = structure($array);
```

I've got the Grandparent working but I can't seem to get it to go over the rest. I've tried putting the loop in side itself to make it search the other children but it will just run infinitely. And I can't put a `foreach` inside a `foreach` and so on because the amount of hashtags can be whatever length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have much time to study this, but this is what I came up with...

1. loop through the array of lines
2. separate the sequence of hash symbols from the member name
3. measure the length of the hash symbol string and compare it against the current level
4. for every instance of a "parent" on a given level, create a reference variable and push it into the output array (tree)
5. everytime you encounter a new "parent" on a given level, the old reference must be destroyed and the new reference declared
6. when recursion is necessary, ONLY pass direct descendants into the recursive call
7. the recursive call needs to be conditionally called at the end of the loop so that unprocessed descendants are handled

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/J9RMQ))

```
function recurse(array $lines, int $level = 1): array
{
    $tree = [];
    $directDescendants = [];
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        [$hashes, $name] = explode(' ', $line, 2);
        $depth = strlen($hashes);
        if ($depth === $level) {
            if ($directDescendants) {
                $parent['children'] = recurse($directDescendants, $level + 1);
            }
            $directDescendants = [];      // reset collection of direct descendants
            unset($parent);               // destroy reference
            $parent = ['name' => $name];  // name the member
            $tree[] = &$parent;           // push the reference variable into the tree
        } elseif ($depth > $level) {
            $directDescendants[] = $line; // collect only direct descendants of current level parent member
        }
    }
    if ($directDescendants) {
        $parent['children'] = recurse($directDescendants, $level + 1);
    }
    return $tree;
}

var_export(recurse($array));
```